# Craft 3 Cannot Save Global Set

Tags: craft3, globals

I am playing around with Craft 3 and for the life of me cannot get it to save an element programmatically.

I am trying to save a Global Set from a module like so:

```
$config = [
    'name' => "My New Global Set",
    'handle' => "mfSet2",
];

$glob = new \craft\elements\GlobalSet($config);

$success = Craft::$app->getGlobals()->saveSet($glob);
```

`$success` returns true and there are no errors. But nothing is saved. There doesn't seem to be any documentation that helps and searching just turns up Craft 2 examples.

Comment: My guess is you're missing the field layout information... check out how Craft's own `controllers\GlobalsController->actionSaveSet()` does it and it should be nearly identical: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/controllers/GlobalsController.php#L55-L96